# Efficient way of extracting data into a matrix or numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to extract data from a txt file while removing the text present in the file using python.

I have a file, say ABC.txt as follows:

STEP = 1

22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
STEP = 2

22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
STEP = 3

22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000
22.530183726628522        0.0000000000000000

disregarding the 'STEP = ' and the following space, I want to store all the numeric data into a numpy array.

I tried the following script that worked :

```
import numpy as np

with open("ABC.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    

data =np.zeros([24,2])

kk=0

for ii in range(3):         
  
    for jj in range(10*ii+2, 10*ii+9+1):
    
        data[kk,:] = np.fromstring(lines[jj], dtype=float, sep=' ')
        kk=kk+1
```

Is there a more direct way of doing this operation ?

Comment: Where are you disregarding the step?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think the two loops are iterating over the right line numbers.

Comment: A common way is read the file line by line.  If the line has data, `split` and append to a list.  `np.array(alist, dtype=float)` will convert the list of lists to a numeric array.  The `step` lines can be ignored or used to start a new group.

Comment: Sorry it's late. Of course they are

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
with open("abc.txt") as f:
    s = f.read()

# get a list of all lines of the text file which start with a digit
lines =  re.findall(r"^\d.*", s, re.M)

# split every line at the space character and convert 
# the resulting substrings into floats 
numlist = [list(map(float, line.split())) for line in lines]

# convert the resulting list of lists of floats into a numpy array
np.array(numlist)
```

Comment: Thank you ! but could you please explain what are we doing here ?

Comment: I added comments to the code. Let me know if this is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't have access to external libraries and still want to perform this task. You can do the following:

```
with open("ABC.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

arr = list()

for line in lines:
    if line[0].isdecimal(): # for every line see if it begins with a decimal number
        arr.append(line.split())
```

The above can also be done with list comprehensions as follows, both will give same results:

```
arr1 = [line.split() for line in lines if line[0].isdecimal()]
```